# Custom route for WP-API gives "rest_no_route" value

Tags: api, rest-api

I am following [this](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-rest-api-customizing-endpoints-adding-new-ones/) tutorial to create custom end points to WP-API .

I am always getting this error  on hitting **/wp-json/custom-plugin/v2/get-all-post-ids/** on **postman** to test :

```
     {  
       "code": "rest_no_route",  
       "message": "No route was found matching
        the URL and request method", 
        "data":
         {
            "status": 404
         }

    }
```

I have created a custom-plugin.php file in /plugins/custom-plugin/ directory .

```
<?php


    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'dt_register_api_hooks' );

    function dt_register_api_hooks() {    

        register_rest_route( 'custom-plugin/v2', '/get-all-post-ids/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'dt_get_all_post_ids',
            ) 
            );

    }


    // Return all post IDs
    function dt_get_all_post_ids() {
        if ( false === ( $all_post_ids = get_transient( 'dt_all_post_ids' ) ) ) {
            $all_post_ids = get_posts( array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_type'   => 'post',
                'fields'      => 'ids',
            ) );
            // cache for 2 hours
            set_transient( 'dt_all_post_ids', $all_post_ids, 60*60*2 );
        }

        return $all_post_ids;
    }

?>
```

Please guide how can i resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code should work, do you use https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/?

Comment: @Jevuska  Yes , i am using WP REST API Version 2.0-beta13  . Can you please test it ?

Comment: Yes' I've test it and it's work.

Comment: @Jevuska But it is not working in my case , what should i do to test properly ?

Comment: I don't know, i just working in local ( it's work ), then I use postman (it's work too)

Comment: @Jevuska can you please share directory path and test link which you used. I will replicate that .Or much better if you post an answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38433/discussion-between-jevuska-and-divyanshu-pathania).

Comment: Stupid question...are you using POST or GET?

Answer (score 1):

I may have the answer to this.

I had POST in my code, but I was trying to look at the URL through a browser.

Make sure you're using the method you specify.